# Imprimir matriz como tal con Python

Tags: python

Tengo que hacer que la matriz se imprima de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que llevo en mi código es esto

```
def sala() :
    butacas =[]
    filas = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
    for i in range(len(filas)) :
        fila = []
        for c in range(0,8) :
            fila.append(filas[i] + str(c+1))
        butacas.append(fila)
    print("PANTALLA".center(31))
    print(butacas)
sala()
```

y en consola sale lineal:
[['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', .... continua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo quieres imprimir, utiliza simplemente dos ciclos anidados junto a un print. No tienes que crear una lista para luego imprimirla. Por ejemplo:

```
def sala() :
    print("PANTALLA".center(22))
    filas = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
    for num in reversed(range(1, 9)):
        for letra in filas:
            print(str(num) + letra, end=" ")
        print()
sala()
```

Cuya salida es:

```
       PANTALLA       
8A 8B 8C 8D 8E 8F 8G 8H 8I 
7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F 7G 7H 7I 
6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F 6G 6H 6I 
5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F 5G 5H 5I 
4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 4G 4H 4I 
3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F 3G 3H 3I 
2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 2G 2H 2I 
1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 1G 1H 1I
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Otra opción sería utilizar comprensión de listas y `join()`

```
def sala() :
    filas = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
    print("PANTALLA".center(26))
    print('\n'.join([' '.join([str(i) + f for f in filas]) for i in range(8,0,-1)]))

sala()
```

Esto devuelve:

```
         PANTALLA         
8A 8B 8C 8D 8E 8F 8G 8H 8I
7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F 7G 7H 7I
6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F 6G 6H 6I
5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F 5G 5H 5I
4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 4G 4H 4I
3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F 3G 3H 3I
2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 2G 2H 2I
1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 1G 1H 1I
```

Comment: Yo usaría comprensiones de generador en lugar de comprensiones de listas.

Comment: Gracias Dante, acabo de hacer pruebas de tiempo de ejecución para ver la diferencia, con comprensión de generador me da `--- 0.0010013580322265625 seconds ---` y con comprensión de listas `--- 0.0 seconds ---`. Pero si incremento el número de filas y columnas la comprensión de generador es más rápida, si el número de filas y columnas es menor a 9 filas y 10 columnas comprensión de listas es más rápido y si es mayor comprensión de generador es más rápido